# Use of optimization in obfuscating C++ code

Tags: c++, optimization, obfuscation

I've been doing some research in obfuscation, I was wondering just how effective optimization is for obfuscating code.

Would optimizing the code remove things from the assembly that would help someone reverse engineer the code?

More generally, what does optimization of code do to make the assembly harder to understand? General answers are fine, I just want to understand the correlation between the two, if any.

Edit: This isn't for a customer, this is for recreational obfuscation and curiosity

Comment: Not terribly effective. Any competent assembly programmer and/or reverse engineer is experienced in reading optimized code, considering it is what everyone sets their compiler to generate for release builds. More generally, obfuscation is not terribly effective. The best you can hope for is to slow down a good reverse engineer, or possibly stop a script kiddie. If your application is worth cracking, someone will crack it. Focus on making it worth cracking, which will also make it worth someone paying for it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is little point in obfuscating C++ code as you deliver to the customer a binary executable or library.

Obfuscation is typically used in interpreted languages to hinder reverse engineering. Then this is done by software so that the original code is readable/maintainable.

As to affecting performance. Obfuscation is typically giving variables/functions random and meaningless names along with removing white space. This will not affect the binary from C compilation. Therefore will not make any difference at all.

Answer (score 2):

Code obfuscation can mean different things. Usually, it refers to tricks that make the code more difficult or impossible to read.

There are no results of obfuscation that specifically relate to optimization. You might be thinking of more terse code that can in some cases (or, at least used to) make the code both harder to read and run more efficiently. But that is generally not the case with today's compilers, and really has nothing to do with obfuscation.

Comment: Heck, if you obfuscate the source well enough, your code may be easier to read by the time the compiler's done optimizing.

Comment: So the use of flags do nothing special to make assembly difficult? When I looked at the debug it looked kinda weird, im suprised that it didn't make much of a difference than i thought it would!

Comment: @JayM. The compiler is going to take the insane, obfuscated mess that is the source code and parse it into [a syntax tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_syntax_tree). Once it has a tree, it will filter the chaff, shift nodes around, and otherwise force a sane order on the tree so that it can make the output program run faster. Then things will get a little crazier again as the tree is converted into machine instructions, but there will be distinct patterns in the output recognizable to those familiar with the processor and compiler.